# How to break out from a fold function in haskell when the accumulator met a certain condition?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I'm calculating the sum of a list after applying `someFunction` to every element of it like so:

```
sum (map someFunction myList)
```

`someFunction` is very resource heavy so to optimise it I want to stop calculating the sum if it goes above a certain threshold.

It seems like I need to use fold but I don't know how to break out if it if the accumulator reaches the threshold. My guess is to somehow compose `fold` and `takeWhile` but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: Almost, but use scanl instead of fold.

Comment: If the sum goes above a threshold or if the outcome of your resource intensive function goes above a threshold?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the options would be using [scanl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) function, which returns a list of intermediate calculations of `foldl`.

Thus, `scanl1 (+) (map someFunction myList)` will return the intermediate sums of your calculations. And since `Haskell` is a lazy language it won't calculate all the values of `myList` until you need it. For example:

```
take 5 $ scanl1 (+) (map someFunction myList)
```

will calculate `someFunction` 5 times and return the list of these 5 results.

After that you can use either [takeWhile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) or [dropWhile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) and stop the calculation, when a certain condition is `True`. For example:

```
head $ dropWhile (< 1000) $ scanl1 (+) [1..1000000000]
```

will stop the calculation, when sum of the numbers reaches 1000 and returns `1035`.

Comment: Perhaps a case to take into consideration is that it is possible that the threshold is never reached, in which case `head` will error.

Comment: maybe i'd use `find` instead of `head` and `dropWhile`: `find (>= 1000) (scanl1 (+) [1..])`

Answer (score 19):

Another technique is to use a `foldM` with `Either` to capture the early termination effect. `Left` signals early termination.

```
import Control.Monad(foldM)

sumSome :: (Num n,Ord n) => n -> [n] -> Either n n
sumSome thresh = foldM f 0
  where
    f a n 
      | a >= thresh = Left a
      | otherwise   = Right (a+n)
```

To ignore the exit status, just compose with `either id id`.

```
sumSome' :: (Num n,Ord n) => n -> [n] -> n
sumSome' n = either id id . sumSome n
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a bounded addition operator instead of `(+)` with `foldl`.

```
foldl (\b a -> b + if b > someThreshold then 0 else a) 0 (map someFunction myList)
```

Because Haskell is non-strict, only calls to `someFunction` that are necessary to evaluate the `if-then-else` are themselves evaluated. `fold` still traverses the entire list.

```
> foldl (\b a -> b + if b > 10 then 0 else a) 0 (map (trace "foo") [1..20])
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
15
```

`sum [1..5] > 10`, and you can see that `trace "foo"` only executes 5 times, not 20.

Instead of `foldl`, though, you should use the strict version `foldl'` from `Data.Foldable.`

Comment: This is cool, and seems like witchcraft, but applied to an infinite list it does hang. I think the trace shows that `a` just isn't forced, although the whole list is traversed.

Comment: Ah, right. I couldn't quite put my finger on why this seemed to work anyway.

Comment: I have been thinking that this lazyness trick is a canonical way to "break out" from folds.

Comment: @arrowd this does _not_ break out from the fold, it keeps adding 0s instead. it doesn't break out from the `map`'s "loop" either, it keeps looping on the input, just stops calling the mapped function. (just commenting for the sake of future visitors here)

Comment: @WillNess if you're saying that `map f [1,2,3]` generates `f x` thunks for each element in the list, you're probably wrong. But to be honest I'm not 100% sure too.

Comment: IIUC, `map f [1,2,3]` generates a single thunk. When you pattern match, e.g. `(t:ts) = map f [1,2,3]`, you'll get two thunks, one for `t = f 1` and one for `ts = map f [2, 3]`.

Comment: @arrowd we're not talking in general about `map`s here. I'm referring to the specific `map` call in the answer as driven by the `foldl` call. this `foldl` will demand every element `a` in its input (as the answer indeed is saying). possibly ignoring its value.

Comment: @WillNess With this I agree. I also wrote `fold still traverses the entire list` in my answer.

Comment: @arrowd I wasn't wrong in what I wrote in that comment though, when I said that "it keeps looping on the input". I wasn't talking about anything else.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you ask about without building the intermediate list as `scanl'` would (and `scanl` would even cause a thunks build-up on top of that):

```
foldl'Breaking break reduced reducer acc list = 
    foldr cons (\acc -> acc) list acc 
          where 
          cons x r acc | break acc x = reduced acc x 
                       | otherwise   = r $! reducer acc x
```

cf. related [wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative).

Answer (score 2):

You *could* try making your own `sum` function, maybe call it `boundedSum` that takes

1. an `Integer` upper bound
2. an `[Integer]` to sum over
3. a "sum up until this point" value to be compared with the upper bound

and returns the sum of the list.

```
    boundedSum :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
    boundedSum upperBound (x : xs) prevSum =
        let currentSum = prevSum + x
            in
        if   currentSum > upperBound
        then upperBound
        else boundedSum upperBound xs currentSum
    boundedSum upperBound [] prevSum =
        prevSum
```

I think this way you won't "eat up" more of the list if the sum up until the current element exceeds upperBound.

**EDIT**: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238399/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-pure-loop-in-haskell-without-hand-written-recursion?rq=1) suggest better techniques than mine and the question itself looks rather similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
last . takeWhile (<=100) . scanl (+) 0 . map (^2) $ [1..]
```

Dissected:

- take your starting list (`[1..]` in the example)
- map your expensive function (`(^2)`)
- compute partial sums `scanl (+) 0`
- stop after the partial sums become too large (keep those `(<=100)`)
- take the last one

If performance matters, also try `scanl'`, which might improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using `until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` from the Prelude

```
sumUntil :: Real a => a -> [a] -> a
sumUntil threshold u = result

    where

    (_, result) = until stopCondition next (u, 0)

    next :: Real a => ([a], a) -> ([a], a)
    next ((x:xs), y) = (xs, x + y)

    stopCondition :: Real a => ([a], a) -> Bool
    stopCondition (ls, x) = null ls || x > threshold
```

Then apply

```
sumUntil 10 (map someFunction myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is already a bit older but I'd like to mention a way to generalize the nice code of @trevor-cook above to break fold with the additional possibility to return not only a default value or the accumulator but also the index and element of the list where the breaking condition was satisfied:

```
import Control.Monad (foldM)

breakFold step initialValue list exitCondition exitFunction = 
  either id (exitFunction (length  list) (last list)) 
      (foldM f initialValue (zip [0..] list))
    where f acc (index,x)
            | exitCondition index x acc 
                        = Left (exitFunction index x acc)
            | otherwise = Right (step index x acc)
```

It also only requires to import `foldM`. Examples for the usage are:

```
mysum thresh list = breakFold (\i x acc -> x + acc) 0 list 
                         (\i x acc -> x + acc > thresh) 
                         (\i x acc -> acc)
myprod thresh list = breakFold (\i x acc -> x * acc) 1 list 
                          (\i x acc -> acc == thresh) 
                          (\i x acc -> (i,x,acc))
```

returning

```
*myFile> mysum 42 [1,1..]
42
*myFile> myprod 0 ([1..5]++[0,0..])
(6,0,0)
*myFile> myprod 0 (map (\n->1/n) [1..])
(178,5.58659217877095e-3,0.0)
```

In this way, one can use the index and the last evaluated list value as input for further functions.

Comment: recalculating the already known values with `length` and `last` seems to indicate an abstraction leakage.

Comment: @Will Ness thanks for reading the code. How would you do it to avoid that?

Comment: You just need to massage it a little bit to pass on the index and the element.

Comment: When I see a top level function with no type signature, my brain turns off.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the age of this post, I'll add a possible solution. I like continuations because I find them very useful in terms of flow control.

```
breakableFoldl
  :: (b -> a -> (b -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r)
  -> b
  -> [a]
  -> (b -> r)
  -> r
breakableFoldl f b (x : xs) = \ exit ->
    f b x exit $ \ acc ->
        breakableFoldl f acc xs exit
breakableFoldl _ b _ = ($ b)

breakableFoldr
  :: (a -> b -> (b -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r)
  -> b
  -> [a]
  -> (b -> r)
  -> r
breakableFoldr f b l = \ exit ->
  fix (\ fold acc xs next ->
    case xs of
      x : xs' -> fold acc xs' (\ acc' -> f x acc' exit next)
      _ -> next acc) b l exit

exampleL = breakableFoldl (\ acc x exit next ->
    ( if acc > 15
      then exit
      else next . (x +)
    ) acc
  ) 0 [1..9] print

exampleR = breakableFoldr (\ x acc exit next ->
    ( if acc > 15
      then exit
      else next . (x +)
    ) acc
  ) 0 [1..9] print
```

Comment: your left fold folds from the right, and your right fold from the left. consider `breakableFoldl  (\acc x exit next -> if x < 5 then exit acc else next ((x:).acc)) id [1..10] ($[100]) ==> [5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` and `breakableFoldr  (\x acc exit next -> if x > 5 then exit acc else next (acc.(x:))) id [1..10] ($[100]) ==> [1,2,3,4,5,11]`.

Comment: That's ok. I'm confident that there are many like me who can't tell left from right. Admittedly most of them are probably under the age of 5, but still...